# attemptedRefreshDate should not be released in FBSession.m

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I am seeing a crash on FBSession.m, line 266. Signal number is 11 (bad memory access.)

See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBSession.m?source=c#L266.

Since _attemptRefreshDate is only being assigned autoreleased values, a "release" message should not get sent to this variable. Please remove this line .. thanks!

Comment: You should open an issue at github instead of asking question here. Please close this question.

Comment: There is no way to post issues for the facebook-ios-sdk on github! This page results in 404: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues